# Add Select Get Value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I want to get **order status name** based on **order_status_id**

I have order statuses in the array:

```
$orderStatuses = [
    1 => 'Waiting',
    2 => 'Delivered',
    3 => 'Rejected'
];
```

I need to get the order status name and order_status_id.

```
$orders = Order::limit(50)->get();
```

I am now only getting order status name from looping through each order like:

```
foreach($orders as $order){
    $order->order_status_name = $orderStatus[$order->order_status_id];
}
```

Is there any way to get the order status name without using foreach.

What I tried:

```
Order::addSelect("$orderStatuses[".'order_status_id'."]". " as order_status_name");
```

I am unable to get the result. Is there any way to get the result from the eloquent query or do I have to use foreach?

Comment: Your order statuses are just a lookup table? Meaning php array and not a table in the database?

Comment: Yes, it is not a table. The key values are stored in an array variable @nakov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an accessor in the `Order` model:

```
private $orderStatuses = [
    1 => 'Waiting',
    2 => 'Delivered',
    3 => 'Rejected'
];

protected $appends = ['status'];

public function getStatusAttribute()
{
    return $this->orderStatuses[$this->order_status_id];
}
```

Then use it in your code as :

```
$order->status;
```

More on this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).

-- EDIT

```
$orders = Order::limit(50)->get();

foreach($orders as $order)
{
    $order->status; // as this is computed property.
}
```

Comment: It is not displaying status when I try to dd(Order::limit(5)->get()). But I get when I try to use Order::first()->status it is working. I also needed for few times, will $appends trigger always when I use Order::get()? or can I manually trigger $appends ?

Comment: Yeah, you need to make the call on an instance of the order model, otherwise it will not show the appended value. But it is there when you foreach over the orders.. Alternatively you can use `Order::get()->toArray()` this should include the status.

Comment: One more. Is there any way not to get status value while doing toArray()?

Comment: @lizeshakya I edited my answer above. Status is always there, not visible on the collection though as it is computed property.

Answer (score 1):

@nakov answer is correct if you want to go with model but if you want to fetch status based on value you can use `case` in query :

```
$data = Order::select("*",\DB::Raw("case when order_status_id = 1 then 'Waiting'  when order_status_id = 2 then 'Delivered' when order_status_id = 3 then 'Rejected' end as status"))
      ->limit(50)
      ->get();
```

It will provide you status field in your collection

```
foreach($orders as $order){
    $order->order_status_name = $order->status;
}
```